# Clear tagged cache from Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to integrate caching in to my Laravel (9) Lighthouse (6) application and private caches seem to work correctly, but I can't seem to find a way to clear them effectively without running `artisan cache:clear`. Take this simplified example:
Query *me* returns authenticated user:

```
extend type Query @guard {
    me: User @auth @cache(private: true)
}
```

Then I want to have a query or mutation which sole purpose is to clear this cache. So I created just that:

```
extend type Mutation @guard {
    userCacheClear(usr_id: ID!): User @update @clearCache(type: "User", idSource: {argument: "usr_id"})
}
```

My `User` type looks like this:

```
type User {
    usr_id: ID! @cacheKey
    usr_username: String
    usr_company: String
}
```

**My problem** is that of course `userCacheClear` returns correct and not cached data, but `me` returns still cached and at this point outdated result.

Am I missing something from the documentation? Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to find the exact solution to my problem because for clearing all user related caches there is no common tag. So I overrode the `Nuwave\Lighthouse\Cache\CacheDirective::handleField` method to include an additional tag to all user private caches.

```
$tags = [
    $this->cacheKeyAndTags->parentTag($parentName, $rootID),
    $this->cacheKeyAndTags->fieldTag($parentName, $rootID, $fieldName)
];

// If cache is private then adding private tag for easier clearing
if($isPrivate) $tags[] = 'auth_' . $context->user()->getAuthIdentifier();

$cache = $shouldUseTags
    ? $this->cacheRepository->tags($tags)
    : $this->cacheRepository;
```

From the code you can see that I check if cache should be private and then add a tag `auth_{user_id}`.

Then registering this change in the `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function register(): void {
    $this->app->bind(CacheDirective::class, CacheDirectiveAdapter::class);
}
```

Now I'm free to run this one-liner to clear all GQL private cache for any specific user.

```
Cache::tags(['auth_{user_id}'])->flush()
```